# jQuery reset form on success error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am submitting a form using ajax and what I need to do is reset the form once a successful submission has been made. However, what is happening is that the form is being cleared once the user submits. I have tried to place the code in Success, Complete but it keeps resetting even if a user receives the error message. I only need to reset after the else statement. ie; The user receives the success message. How can I correct this. Thanks

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "boxrtrvajax.php",
      cache: false,
      data: send,
      success: function (data) {
      if (data == 'No data'){
      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html('Please fill in all fields');
      }

      else

      //location.reload(true);
      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html("You have successfully retrieved: "+data).fadeIn(4000).delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
      $("#BRV-brtrv-slider").val(0).slider("refresh");
      $("input[type='radio']").attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
      var myselect = $("select#BRV-brtrv-department");
      myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
      myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
      var myselect = $("select#BRV-brtrv-address");
      myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
      myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
      },

      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      jAlert('There was an exception thrown somewhere');
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have brackets around your else statement so it completes the code no matter what

```
 if (data == 'No data')
      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html('Please fill in all fields');
 else
 {
      //location.reload(true);
      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html("You have successfully retrieved: "+data).fadeIn(4000).delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
      $("#BRV-brtrv-slider").val(0).slider("refresh");
      $("input[type='radio']").attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
      var myselect = $("select#BRV-brtrv-department");
      myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
      myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
      var myselect = $("select#BRV-brtrv-address");
      myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
      myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
  }
```